# Which Has a Larger Volume a Cylinder or a Truncated Cone?

Tags: calculus, geometry

The [following link](https://www.e-olymp.com/en/contests/3438/problems/28074) describes a programming problem. However, I am unable to work out the maths for the problem.

> We are given $r$ – radius of lower base and $s$ – slant height. The figure can be cylinder or truncated cone. You have to find as largest volume as possible to carry oil respect to given information.
>
> You are given two numbers that less than 100: radius $r$ of lower base and slant height $s$. The slant height is the shortest possible distance between the edges of two bases.

EDIT suggested :

Given $ \sqrt{(R-r)^2 + h^2 }$ and $ r,$  find $ h/r $ ratio.

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$[image]

Comment: Seems like a simple optimization problem. But you should include the problem in the body of your post because link-only posts are frowned upon in this community.

Comment: Could you please say more about where you can't make progress? Do you know how to find the volume of a cylinder/truncated cone given appropriate dimensions? Can you calculate those dimensions in terms of the information given in the question?

Comment: The problem here is that the area of the truncated cone requires 2 values for radius but only one value is given. The resulting volume will have those 2 variables whereas in the case of a cylinder, you have 1 value only. I guess you have to use the fact that the upper circle in the cone is smaller than the lower circle and build an inequality. However, it would look complex.

Comment: @apoorvasomani: Could you please clarify whether this contest problem is still "live"?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang the site says the competition was from Nov 24, 2013, 11:00:02 AM to  Nov 24, 2013, 4:00:02 PM

Comment: @G-man: Thanks. I had a glance at the linked page but didn't see dates, then some time later started to wonder when (seemingly) [the same question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1615699) got asked again. (Separately, I do appreciate your checking, but it's the OP's responsibility to make this type of issue clear.)

Comment: @apoorvasomani Is the edit ok? I had put in constant slant length. If not ok, feel free to change or delete.

Answer (score 1):

See on comparing volume we get to see that volume of cylinder $<$ volume of truncated cone as $r^2<(r^2+R^2-rR)$. Thus from here you can setup equations and differentiate it with radius and then put it to be $0$ for maxima and the condition for maxima is $f''(x)<0$

Comment: Please detail your answer. As is it is not clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

If the constant slant height and base radius are $s, r$ respectively and the variable angle which the slanting face makes with the vertical is $\theta$ then the height and top radius of the frustum are
$$h=s\cos\theta, R=r+s\sin\theta$$

The volume of the frustum is $$V=\frac13 \pi h (R^2+Rr+r^2)$$
Now $$\frac{dh}{d\theta}=-s\sin\theta, \frac{dR}{d\theta}=s\cos\theta$$
Volume is maximum when
$$\frac{dV}{d\theta}=\frac13 \pi [\frac{dh}{d\theta}(R^2+Rr+r^2)+h(2R\frac{dR}{d\theta}+r\frac{dR}{d\theta})=0$$
$$-s\sin\theta (R^2+Rr+r^2)+s\cos\theta(2Rs\cos\theta+rs\cos\theta)=0$$
$$-s\sin\theta (3r^2+3rs\sin\theta+s^2\sin^2\theta)+s^2(1-\sin^2\theta)(3r+2s\sin\theta)=0$$
$$- (3r^2\sin\theta+3rs\sin^2\theta+s^2\sin^3\theta)+(3rs+2s^2\sin\theta-3rs\sin^2\theta-2s^2\sin^3\theta)=0$$
$$3x+(2-3x^2)y-6xy^2-3y^3=0$$
where $x=r/s$ and $y=\sin\theta$.

In general the cubic equation will have to be solved numerically. In the special case $s=r$ so that $x=1$ we have $3-y-6y^2-3y^3=0$. The only real root is $y=\sin\theta\approx 0.56298, \cos\theta\approx 0.82647$. Then the maximum volume is $V\approx 4.33$ as found in the link. Whereas for the cylinder $V=\pi\approx 3.14$.